# Injecting username and credentials into command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to automatically fill a username and password box that the command I run asks for. Specifically:

`net use v: https://d.docs.live.net/xxxxxxxxxx`

which asks for a username and password.

would I be right in thinking if you set this as a batch file, you could then use the `run as` command to inject the appropriate username and password into the batch file?

[Here's the prompt on the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAnCN.png)

Comment: `net use v: https://d.docs.live.net/xxxxxx /user:username password` - Try that instead.

Comment: Cheers n8te. Worked a treat!